# Added team member cannot see project despite similar permissions

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-devops

We have a project administrator for a collection of projects on TFS Online. We recently hired so he had to add the guy as a new member into the team.

However he cannot see one specific project we have, even with identical permissions as the other users. His account was created in the same way as the others.

Trying to help the guy out here I offered to try a few things and noticed, If I create a new project as a test. "Test1", and add him as a member, he can see this account fine when he logs in to TFS Online/Connects on Visual Studio. 
Which leads me to believe that it's based on some visibility setting within TFS, even though the other members linked to the project can see it fine.

Any possible ideas for me to try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to try and trace his effective permissions. It sounds like there is a denied somewhere.

If you open the admin for that team project and goto the security tab there is a box to add the users account. You should then see the effective permission on the right and he should have and Alowed in the "View project level information" permission.

If he does bot you can roll your mouse over it and click the "why" button and you will see where the overide is coming from.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'll take a look and see and get back to you

Comment: that did the trick. Seen that the setting was implicitly denied, followed through the groups to the end and set it to allow. Thanks very much!