# Cannot see a team project that I was able to see before

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I'm using VS 2010 Professional. There was a team project that I was able to see and use in the past, that I now can't.

I can't understand why this has changed, I checked permissions and everything looks fine (also checked this solution: [Added team member cannot see project despite similar permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28304194/added-team-member-cannot-see-project-despite-similar-permissions)).

Tried reconnecting and some other quick solutions but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas what I can do to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: In the web portal are you able to see the project? (the code section)

Comment: Do you use VSTS or on-premise TFS? Could you please share a screenshot of your team explorer?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the replies.

Comment: @Shayki, I don't think I understand what you mean, I'm new to this so I'm still not familiar with everything.

Comment: @Cece I'm using VSTS, I will upload a screenshot in a few minutes.

Comment: @BarakB Shayki means you can go to tfs web portal, and check whether you can see the your code under `Code` tab.

Comment: https://ibb.co/erR7M8 This is a screenshot of my team explorer, as you can see I can only see "My fav". I used to be able to see a team project where the red line is.

Comment: And I can't find a Code tab in the web portal. Perhaps Im not looking at the right place? I got to my web portal from VS, Team tab -> Team project collection settings -> Security

Comment: From your screenshot, it seems you are using on-premise TFS, not VSTS. Which version of TFS are you using? You should go to `http://TFS:8080/tfs/teamprojectcollection/` to see whether you can see the team projects.

Comment: Ah, sorry for misleading, I thought VSTS means Visual Studio's TFS, how can I check my TFS ver.? PS I just realized that if I go to  Team project settings -> Security -> Server Settings, I can't see the team project there as well.

Comment: BTW, this link isn't working for me http://TFS:8080/tfs/teamprojectcollection/. also tried changing to TFS1.

Comment: Your link should be as `http://TFS1:8080/tfs/SilverArrowCollection/`, did you try that?

Comment: This link does work. However I can't see anything relevant here. Under "Projects" all I see is a form to create a new project, does that mean I don't see any?

Comment: Yes, it seems you are not added to any team projects or not granted permission to see team projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go to Team project settings -> Security, search your account and check whether you have `View team project-level information` permission.

Comment: Hi again, as mentioned in the post, I already tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28304194/added-team-member-cannot-see-project-despite-similar-permissions, and I do have the view team project-level info (inherited allow).

Comment: Since you can't see the team projects, how did you check your permission in for a particular team project? You could open your TFS Administration Console and navigate to `Application Tier` to check the TFS version. Also, navigate to `Team Project Collections -- Team Projects` to check whether the team projects there, and check the team projects status under `status` tab.

Comment: Correction: I have "View *instance-level* info" as inherited allow, rather than project level. I can't find the project-level field though. I also cannot find "Application tier", Perhaps you are mistaking me for an admin? There's a different window with different tabs from the ones you have, I think. And I don't see my team projects under a tab like Team Project Collection (found some equivalent tab)

Comment: If I go to Security -> my user -> Member of, I can see the name of my team project there (under "Username or Scope")

Comment: @BarakB You need to contact your team project administration or TFS server admin to check your permission, it's supposed you have been added to some group that don't have `View team project-level information` permission, or the team project doesn't exist any more.

Comment: Already did, he couldn't help ( yea ... :) ), but I guess you are right and it's only a matter of permissions, my boss says it too. Thanks alot for your time and help.